# A question involving condition for an element to be in the kernel of a representation ans the kernel of the coset representation

Tags: representation-theory

I came across the following question.

Given a representation $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ with kernel $N$, let $\rho$ have character χ : $G$ → $\mathbb C$. Then for $g ∈ G$, it first asks to prove that $g ∈ N$ if and only if $χ(g) = d$.

Also, given a subgroup $H$ of $G$ and {$g_1, g_2, . . . , g_k$} a transversal for $H$ in $G$, it asks to prove that the kernel of the coset representation is $N=\cap g_{i}Hg_{i}^{-1}$.

I'd like to see a solution to the problems. Are they even related?

Answer (score 0):

(1): bound ${\rm Re}\,\chi$ using the fact that trace equals the sum of eigenvalues.

(2): show the kernel of any group action is the intersection of all point-stabilizers.

The problems are both about kernels of representations, that's about all the relation I see.